# What is $dm$ in the center of mass formula in the $y$-direction $y_{cm} = \frac{\int y\ dm}{\int dm}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass

I want to figure out the **COM (Center of Mass)** of an infinitesimally thin semicircular ring of uniform density with mass $M$ and radius $R$.

---

I begin to draw the following picture:

[image: Image of a semicircular ring]

As I have understood it, the typical way to go about solving these kinds of problems is to try and think of the rigid body as it consisting of an infinite amount of point particles. Each particle will have a **COM** $m_{i}\bar{r_{i}}$ with $\bar{r_{i}}$ being the position vector of the **COM** for particle $i$. By summing up all of these infinite **COMs** and dividing by the total mass of the particles $M$, we obtain the **COM** of a system of particles.

The equations for the **COM** in the $y$- and $x$ directions are

$$ x_{cm} = \frac{\int x\ dm}{\int dm},\ \ \ \text{The position vector is }x = Rcos(\theta) $$

$$ y_{cm} = \frac{\int y\ dm}{\int dm},\ \ \ \text{The position vector is }y = Rsin(\theta), $$

but what is $dm$? It feels reasonable that $dm$ is the mass of the point particle whose location is given by the position vector $\bar{r_{i}}$. How do I figure out what that mass is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to think of $dm$ as an *infinitessimal mass element* instead of a point particle. Usually you use the density to write $\text dm$ in terms of an infinitessimal volume/area/distance which you can integrate. Depending on the number of dimensions you get the following expressions for $\text dm$
\begin{align}
\text dm&=\rho(x)\text dV&\text{in 3D}\\
\text dm&=\sigma(x)\text d A& \text{in 2D}\\
\text dm&=\lambda(x)\text ds&\text{in 1D}
\end{align}
Where $\rho,\sigma, \lambda$ are the density, area density and linear density respectively (sometimes different notation is used). Your problem is one dimensional and has uniform density so we can put $\text dm=\lambda \text ds$ where $\lambda$ is now constant. Before we can calculate $\text ds$ we first have to parametrize the domain. Define $s$ as the path length along the arc
$$s(\theta)=R\theta\implies\text ds=R\text d\theta$$

We can now write the integral as
\begin{align}
x_\text{COM}&=\dfrac{\int \lambda(R\text d\theta)(R\cos\theta)}{\int \lambda(R\text d\theta)}
\end{align}

Comment: The ring is meant to be infinitesimally thin, so we only want a density in one dimension, not two dimensions.

Comment: @J.G. I totally missed that, I updated my answer

Comment: Your explanation seems the easiest and most straight forward. We have a *linear density* $dm = \lambda (x) ds$ with $ds = Rd \theta$. Plugging in $\lambda(Rd \theta)$ into the integrals and evaluating yields $x_{cm} = 0$ and $y_{cm} = \frac{2R}{\pi}$ which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're told the linear density is uniform, so it must be $\frac{M}{R\pi}$. Since the infinitesimal arc length is $Rd\theta$, $dm=\frac{M}{R\pi}Rd\theta=\frac{M}{\pi}d\theta$.

Comment: So $\frac{M}{R \pi}$ is the *uniform surface density* call it $\sigma$. $\sigma = \frac{M}{R \pi}$ with $R \pi = A$ the surface area? I understand that the infinitesimal arc length is $Rd \theta$ but why do we multiply the arc length with the *surface density* and call that $dm$? If possible, would you mind visualizing $dm$ in a perhaps more detailed way than I have?

Comment: @NoName123 It's a _linear_ density in one dimension, so it's multiplied by a length to get a mass. If the thickness in a second dimension were some positive amount, say $\epsilon$, we'd have a surface density $\frac{M}{R\pi\epsilon}$ (well, technically $\frac{M}{\tfrac12\pi\left[R^2-(R-\epsilon)^2\right]}=\frac{2M}{\pi\epsilon(2R-\epsilon)}$). But that would be a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{d}m$ is an infinitesimal mass $m$, corresponding to what you call "point particles".

But they're not really point particles, they are infinitesmally small volume elements:

$$\mathrm{d}V=\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z$$

so that:

$$\mathrm{d}m=\rho \mathrm{d}V$$

Assuming $\rho$ (density) to be constant then the object's total mass $m$ is:

$$m=\rho \int_{Volume}\mathrm{d}V=\rho V_{total}$$

In thecase of your system,

$$\mathrm{d}V=\pi r \mathrm{d}r$$

Comment: The ring is meant to be infinitesimally thin, so we only want a density in one dimension, not three dimensions.

Comment: My approach was simply general. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It's not _wrong_, but it's only applicable here with some Dirac delta specifics. It's easier just to work in one dimension.